# CSS div title position

Tags: css, html, title

Is it possible to make a div title appear like this:

[image]

I know that I could the the text "Div Title here" inside a div, give it a solid background and position it with absolute coordinates, but I would like the title to be associated with the div, instead of whole document, so I can move the div without worrying about moving the title.

I have set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Eth6U/.

Comment: Ever seen the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags?

Comment: Nope, not yet, I guess that is what I need.

Comment: Wouldn't this be possible to achieve with fieldset with legend and some css? Bummer, too late. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `<fieldset>` tag for doing this...

Here's an example...

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Div title here...</legend>
</fieldset>
```

You can edit the `<fieldset>` tag just as a `<div>` in CSS...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `fieldset` and the `legend` tags.

For example:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>The title</legend>
    <p>hello!</p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you're looking for [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset) and [`legend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/legend).

```
<fieldset>  
  <legend>Title</legend>  
  ...
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed [on SitePoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?609458-CSS-needed-to-put-text-in-a-border) and it seemed the best way to do it was to nest a div within a div and use negative margins to position it correctly, which I believe you don't want to do.

What you are trying to do is very similar to the fieldset legend for forms and you can use that html and style it with CSS to customise it's look. [Examples](http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Div Title Here</legend>
<!-- Write your code here what do you want in that fieldset-->
</fieldset>
```